# Can "why" ever be used as a subordinating conjunction?

Tags: grammar, sentence, conjunctions

I posted an image of a list of subordinating conjunctions for my students today, and one of them asked about "why" on the list. I couldn't think of any example where "why" would be used as a subordinating conjunction.

There are multiple lists out there with "why" included.

Am I taking crazy pills? Is "why" a subordinating conjunction?

Comment: _Why_ they don’t include examples, we aren’t told.

Comment: Although ***why*** doesn't make it into [this list of 10 subordinating conjunctions](https://www.mvorganizing.org/what-are-the-7-subordinating-conjunctions/), it's there in [this list of ***27*** subordinating conjunctions](https://www.bkacontent.com/what-are-subordinating-conjunctions/). But such "named syntactic categories" are often misleading, because almost all actual ***words*** in English can fit multiple categories. ***Without specific example contexts, such categories are effectively worthless***.

Comment: ... and [Grammarly](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subordinating_conjunctions.htm) suggests a longer list. But CGEL discounts the 'traditional' view of 'subordinating conjunctions' anyway.

Comment: _Why_ isn't a conjunction, let alone a special type of conjunction. _Why_, like _who, what, which, where, when, whether, how,_ (and occasionally _whither_ and _whence_), is a _Wh_-word. That's a special class of English words that serve as relative pronouns and adverbs, question words, and complement markers. In the latter category they introduce embedded question complement clauses, like the one in @Lawrence's comment above. This doesn't make them subordinate conjunctions, though; that's a wastebasket category.

Comment: No, it's not a conjunction. CGEL and most dictionaries properly classify "why" as an adverb.

Comment: I think this is an example of using it as a subordinating conjunction: "I told you *why* I did that."